# NextAuth's JWT_SESSION_ERROR Invalid time period format

Tags: keycloak, next-auth

I'm running NextAuth 4.21.1 with Keycloak.

The following is how the content of `[...nextauth].js` looks like,

```
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER,
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    maxAge: 600,
  },
  callbacks: {
  },
  debug: true,
});
```

and I have defined `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` in the `.env`,

```
KEYCLOAK_ID=myweb
KEYCLOAK_SECRET=ZeJk8aXF76MqGVqzapZAZmqiso2oywMt
KEYCLOAK_ISSUER=http://localhost:8666/realms/myrealm
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=rwCUC5x1POp45NdY7JXH1lF/jSJvwz+qUZ6JB1sxmkU=
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

The following error was thrown when run in development,

```
[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error Invalid time period format {
  message: 'Invalid time period format',
  stack: 'TypeError: Invalid time period format\n' +
    '    at exports.default (C:\\Temp\\node_modules\\jose\\dist\\node\\cjs\\lib\\secs.js:12:15)\n' +
    '    at EncryptJWT.setExpirationTime (C:\\Temp\\node_modules\\jose\\dist\\node\\cjs\\jwt\\produce.js:44:114)\n' +
    '    at Object.encode (C:\\Temp\\node_modules\\next-auth\\jwt\\index.js:52:20)\n' +
    '    at async Object.session (C:\\Temp\\node_modules\\next-auth\\core\\routes\\session.js:67:24)\n' +
    '    at async AuthHandler (C:\\Temp\\node_modules\\next-auth\\core\\index.js:158:27)\n' +     
    '    at async NextAuthHandler (C:\\Temp\\node_modules\\next-auth\\next\\index.js:24:19)\n' +  
    '    at async C:\\Temp\\node_modules\\next-auth\\next\\index.js:60:32',
  name: 'TypeError'
}
```

Do you have any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is directly related to your time format. Even though a number value for `maxAge` is valid according to documentation, it's prevented on the runtime check. (https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/main/src/lib/secs.ts#L8)

You can try to change `maxAge` value from 600 to "600s"